# Add a ViewController to a view inside a Window based application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Ok this is an easy one for most of you and a pretty basic question, but I quite don't get the full concept yet .

I've got a window based application, it contains 2 views, so far so good, everything is working but now I`m trying to do a modalTransition, which requires a ViewController ( which I don't have ) . What is the best way to attach a ViewController to one of those existing views in my Window so I can start playing with ModalTransitions ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your navigation controller to your AppDelegate. There is a good video tutorial in Youtube which combines navigation controller and tab bar, check it if you want:[video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw&feature=related)